# How to plot the graph of this expression which involves Dirac delta function?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, singularities, dirac-delta-distributions

I was doing a problem on electrostatics which required finding the charge density from the given electric field and then plot a graph of the charge density. I was able to find the charge density which is

$$\rho=\frac {-Ab \epsilon_0}{r^2} \cdot e^{-br}+4 \pi \epsilon_0 A \delta(r)$$

but was not able plot it. When i looked the solution i was not able to understand it.

[image]

The reason for my confusion is the point $r=0$ where the left term is minus infinity and the right term is plus infinity. Can any one help me?

Comment: Cross-posted from Math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977527

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the function cannot be plotted, in the sense that your graph cannot stretch all the way to infinity. The behaviour near the origin is such that as $r$ gets smaller the function goes more and more negative as long as $r > 0$, and then it shoots off to $+\infty$ at $r=0$. This is because the singular behaviour of the delta function is sharper than the $1/r^2$ function.

No physical density will really be infinite in practice; the point charge and the Dirac delta function are mathematically convenient ways to deal with a charge whose spatial extent is negligible compared to other distances in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> When i looked the solution i was not able to understand it.

$\let\d=\delta \def\vr{\vec r}$
No wonder. Nobody can understand it. A "$\delta$-function" cannot be plotted, since it is no function. At best you can plot something which "approximates"a $\d$.

But the very "solution" you report is worse. You didn't give us the problem text, and we can only back-engineer it from its solution. However, if the $\d(r)$ is meant to represent a point charge in the origin, it is wrong. It should have been 
$\d^{(3)} (\vec r)$.

Can you see the difference? And why $\d^{(3)}(\vr)$ is meaningful, whereas $\d(r)$ is meaningless in present context?